# How to programmatically add a custom html url to the Workflow Task's description column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, workflow, 2013, tasks

How can I update the description column of a workflow task in SharePoint 2013 using c# that will contain a html link that has to open in a new window.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...

```
    // Set a couple of format constants
    // Approval Page url format
    public const string ApprovalPageUrlFormat = @"http://{0}/it/SitePages/ChangeRequestWFApproval.aspx?rid={1}";
    public const string TaskDescriptionLinkHtmlFormat = @"Please click <a href='{0}' target='_blank'>here</a> to approve the request";

    private void myCreateTaskWithContentType_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            // Set Other Task Properties

            // Create the url 
            string url = string.Format(ApprovalPageUrlFormat,
                    Environment.MachineName.ToLower(), currentItem.UniqueId.ToString());

            // Assign the url
            myWorkflowTaskProperties.Description = string.Format(TaskDescriptionLinkHtmlFormat, url);




    }
```